# Moqui:Can we create parent and child relation between two users

Tags: moqui

I just want to create one organization(Pharmacy) and under that organization need a different kinds of user like admin user, inventory user, billing user......etc

Comment: More details are needed to answer this question. Are you trying to setup security like authorization for groups of users? This would be done with moqui-framework entities like UserGroup and related. If you are trying to setup an organization structure that goes beyond access control settings and gets into the business domain where Mantle Business Artifacts would apply. The main entities there are Party and PartyRelationship, and there is demo data with org structures.

Comment: I am trying to create an organization with set of users, Users can able to login and able to access the system based on their roles.Achieving  Roles and Privileges for uses by using UserGroup and UserGroupMember entities but not able to achieve organization concept here.

Comment: Let say ['Phrmaacy1'] is an organization and  ['Admin1'] is the admin user for the 'Phrmaacy1' ,['Inventory1'] is a inventory user for the 'Phrmaacy1'  here admin and inventory user should mapped with the organization('Phrmaacy1' )....same like  ['Phrmaacy2'] is one more organization and  ['Admin2'] is the admin user for the 'Phrmaacy2' ,['Inventory2'] is a inventory user for the 'Phrmaacy2'  here admin and inventory user should mapped with the organization('Phrmaacy2' ) and here user from one pharmacy should not access the data of other pharmacy

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there are two dimensions of data control

- by userGroup
- by organization

So the solution would be:

- create organization ['Phrmaacy1', 'Phrmaacy2']
- create person ['Admin1', 'Admin2', 'Inventory1', 'Inventory2'], and userAccount for these persons
- create userGroup ['Admin', 'Inventory']
- create partyRelationship ['Admin1', 'Inventory1'] as member of ['Phrmaacy1'], and ['Admin2', 'Inventory2'] as member of ['Phrmaacy2']
- create userGroupMember to put userAccount of person ['Admin1', 'Admin2'] in userGroup ['Admin'], userAccount of person ['inventory1', 'inventory2'] in userGroup ['Inventory']

Use both organization and userGroup the user belong to to filter out data, and use userGroup (userGroupPermissions, artifactAuthz) to control permission the user is allowed to perform.